# MySQL query is slow - difference in successive dates at the group level

Tags: mysql

Below is my MySQL query to find the difference between successive date for each account and then using the results to prepare a frequency count table. This query is of course very slow but before that am I doing the right thing? Please help if you can. Also embedded is a small data sample.
Appreciate your time.
OZooHA

```
     ID    DATE
    403    2008-06-01
    403    2012-06-01
    403    2011-06-01
    403    2010-06-01
    403    2009-06-01
  15028    2011-07-01
  15028    2010-07-01
  15028    2009-07-01
  15028    2008-07-01

SELECT 
    month_diff, 
    count(*) 
FROM
(SELECT t1.id, 
        t1.date, 
        MIN(t2.date) AS lag_date, 
        TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, t1.date, MIN(t2.date)) AS month_diff
FROM    tbl_name T1
        INNER JOIN tbl_name T2
            ON  t1.id = t2.id
            AND t2.date > t1.date
GROUP BY t1.id, t1.date
ORDER BY t1.id, t1.date
)
GROUP BY month_diff
ORDER BY month_diff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely, materializing the inline view is taking most of the time. Ensure you have suitable indexes available to improve performance of the join operation; a covering index `ON tbl_name (id, date)` would likely be optimal for this query.

With a suitable index available (as above) it may be possible to get better performance with a query something like this:

```
SELECT d.month_diff
     , COUNT(*)
  FROM ( SELECT IF(@prev_id = t.id
                  , TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, t.date, @prev_date )
                  , NULL
                ) AS month_diff
              , @prev_date := t.date
              , @prev_id   := t.id
           FROM tbl_name t
          CROSS
           JOIN (SELECT @prev_date := NULL, @prev_id := NULL) i
          GROUP BY t.id DESC, t.date DESC
       ) d
 WHERE d.month_diff IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY d.month_diff
```

Note that the usage of MySQL user-defined variables is not guaranteed. But we do observe consistent behavior with queries written in a particular way. (Future versions of MySQL may change the behavior we observe.)

---

EDIT:  I modified the query above, to replace the `ORDER BY t.id, t.date` with a `GROUP BY t.id, t.date`... It's not clear from the example data whether `(id,date)` is guaranteed to be unique. (If we do have that guarantee, then we don't need the GROUP BY, we can just use ORDER BY. Otherwise, we need the `GROUP BY` to get the same result returned by the original query.)

Comment: Why have you bothered to initialise your @'s to null? You could scrap that cross join.

Comment: @Arth: Because otherwise we have no guarantee what values will be in `@prev_id` and `@prev_date` the first time they're referenced in the statement. Yes, the cross join to the inline view could be scrapped, and could be replaced with separate `SET @prev_date = NULL` and `SET @prev_id = NULL` statements. (The user defined variables persist in the session, we don't know what values are stored in them when the statement begins executing; we can demonstrate getting a "wrong" result if those aren't initialized. (My preference is to include the initialization of the udvs within the statement.)

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for that. I wasn't thinking outside the statement!

Comment: **WOW** it got done in less than 3 secs when the original took like forever. I had to just modify the group by t.id to order by as the (id,date) is guaranteed to be unique.Hats off to you sir.